# Get last n folder name

Tags: python

I'm working on a python project that will frequently loop to detect any new folder created in a directory and insert the new folder name into database.

This is shape of the directory and the folders inside it:

```
C:\USERS\DESKTOP\RESULT
├───20220819_160033
├───20220819_162117
├───20220819_192122
├───20220820_080920
├───20220820_094355
├───20220902_081328
└───20220902_083015
```

**The current algorithm:**

I retrieve the previous folder count that have been saved in the database and compared it with current folder counts.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc, os

# Connect to SQL Server
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                    'Server=server;'
                    'Database=folder;'
                    'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM FileLog ORDER BY FileID DESC")
prevFileCount = cursor.fetchone()
fileCount = prevFileCount[3] # <--- retrieve previous filecounts

name = []
count = 0

dir_path = r'C:\USERS\DESKTOP\RESULT'
# Iterate directory
for path in os.listdir(dir_path): # Calculate current folder counts
    # check if current path is a file
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir_path, path)):
        name.append(os.path.join(dir_path, path))
        count += 1
```

The idea is, if current counts is more than previous counts, the system will take the total `n` different and using it to get the last `n` folder name and save it into database. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59717913/16338695) help but how can I get last `n` folder name instead of only the last.

Comment: That example already shows how to get `sorted_files`, sorted by file date, so you can just get the first or last `n` with `sorted_files[:10]` or `sorted_files[-10:]` respectively.

Comment: Side-notes: 1) `os.scandir` will significantly improve performance here (it gets the `isdir` information for free as part of the scan, so no `stat` is necessary unless the item is a symlink, and even then it caches the result of the `stat`). 2) If you're running on Linux, the inotify functionality of the Linux kernel (exposed in some PyPI packages, e.g. [`inotify`](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/)) will give you direct notification of directory modifications as they happen without needing to poll.

Comment: @Grismar: There's also the option of using `heapq.nlargest`/`heapq.nsmallest`, but unless the directories are *huge* (and `scandir` is used to avoid pulling all the data at once), whatever benefit it *might* have over `sorted`+slicing is lost in the noise of the cost of I/O.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, at the core, what you're asking is: *How to fetch directory names excluding up to n-th oldest.* - n being the number in the DB.

While I think it might be better to [utilize `watchdog` in that case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69117297/using-watchdog-to-put-newly-created-file-names-into-variables/69118747#69118747) - Storing any new directories in list and add to DB periodically.

But if situation not allows, such as accounting for new directory while script was offline - Maybe [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib%20path#) helps.

Following code is expecting file names are corresponding to created date as shown in your example.

```py
import itertools
import pathlib

DIR_PARENT = pathlib.Path("parent_path")

DIR_COUNT = 5  # pretend we fetched recorded directory count

# prepare directory literator, filtering out files.
dir_iter = (path for path in DIR_PARENT.iterdir() if path.is_dir())

# drop first n items from directory literator, won't consume much mem.
new_dirs = [path_ for path_ in itertools.islice(dir_iter, DIR_COUNT, None)]

# now do whatever you want to do with list
# for i.e. printing names
for p in new_dirs:
    print(p)

# counting is just as simple
print(len(new_dirs))
```

Unless newly added directory list are giant, it shouldn't use much memory while iterating thru, and can operate with much ease than `os.path` is.

---

#### Demo

Directory:

```
~ $ tree
.
├── 20220819_160033
├── 20220819_162117
├── 20220819_192122
├── 20220820_080920
├── 20220820_094355
├── 20220902_081328
├── 20220902_083015
└── not_a_dir.notdir
```

```py
>>> import pathlib
>>> import itertools
>>> dir_iter = (path for path in pathlib.Path("./").iterdir() if path.is_dir())
>>> new_dirs = [path_ for path_ in itertools.islice(dir_iter, 5, None)]
>>> new_dirs
[PosixPath('20220902_081328'), PosixPath('20220902_083015')]

# two newest directories fetched
```